# How to get book cover images over https by google book api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, https

I am using google book api to get books information. I can get everything right but I need to get book cover image links over https.

now its like this,

```
"thumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=UMq0HqrufZ8C&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api"
```

I would like to get like this,

```
"thumbnail": "https://books.google.com/books/content?id=UMq0HqrufZ8C&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api"
```

my controller is,

```
def search
  @result = params[:search_words]
  escaped_address = URI.escape("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=#{@result}&maxResults=10")
  uri = URI.parse(escaped_address)
  json = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
  @hash = JSON.parse(json)
  @book = Book.new
end
```

any help appreciated. Thank you for advance!

Comment: can you please elaborate what is the issue you are facing because both the thumbnail URLs you added above work fine *http://* and *https://* ?
Assuming your question is how to get the secure *URL* for the image, I think you can just do 
```"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=UMq0HqrufZ8C&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api".gsub("http", "https")```

Note: this is the easiest possible way to do this, there might be more efficient solution.